# Time to FCP changes based on order of <h2> and <p> tags

Tags: performance, optimization, google-pagespeed

I was troubleshooting why one particular page took a full second longer to reach FCP compared to similar pages for mobile according to Google's Page Insights.  The difference ended up being the order of two tags at the beginning of the page.

3.4 seconds to FCP

```
<h2>heading</h2>
<p>some paragraph</p>
```

versus 2.5 seconds to FCP

```
<p>opening paragraph</p>
<h2>heading</h2>
```

In the first scenario, Google Page Insights gave a logo from the header as the FCP content.  But with the second scenario, Google would display either text from the `<p>` or `<h2>` tag for the FCP content.

Why would the order of these two simple tags change the FCP content from text to an image header?

Comment: These sound like bogus metrics to me if they are so arbitrary.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  Are you saying Google's metrics are arbitrary?

Comment: Do you get the same results for multiple test? Could it be caused by other factors like a temporary slow down on your server? Are Google Metrics really reliable if I understand @StephenOstermiller?

Comment: They are either arbitrary or maybe their tool isn't measuring them correctly.

Comment: @gael, I've done the test several times over several days.  Always the same.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm guessing you're correct.  GTMetrix doesn't show any difference.between the two versions.  But it makes me wonder what impact these "bogus" metrics might have on SERPs.

Comment: Google provides those metrics in the hope that they are useful to you, but I don't think they are using them as a direct ranking signal.   Google has been penalizing *very* slow sites (10 second page loads), and getting page loads under 3 seconds makes big enough usability improvements that that indirectly helps rankings.  However, I don't know of anybody that has improved rankings by tweaking their site to improve more than that.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, thanks for the info about 3 seconds being a threshold.  I'm also seing other pages with the same order of tags having FCP timing issues.

Comment: That isn't to say that improving load speed further isn't worth it, it just doesn't help SEO.  It may still help  usability, stickiness, conversions, and other metrics you care a lot about.